# coefficient of poles of meromorphic function on a Riemann surface does not depend on the local coordinate

Tags: riemann-surfaces, meromorphic-functions

Suppose $M$ is a Riemann surface and $f$ is a meromorphic function on $M$ who has a pole at $p$ of degree $n$. If $w,z$ are both local coordinates around $p$ such that $w(0)=z(0)=p$, then $f$ has a Laurent series power at $p$ as
$$ f(z) =\sum_{j=-n}^\infty a_{j}z^j $$
$$ f(w) =\sum_{j=-n}^\infty b_{j}w^j $$

will $a_{-n}=b_{-n}$ holds?

Comment: Let $M=\mathbb{C}, p=0$. Let $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}, w=2z$.  Then $f(w) =\frac{2}{w}; a_{-1}=1, b_{-1} = 2$

Comment: what if $M$ is compact?

Comment: Isn't the question still local? Ie, the expansion depends on the local behavior near p, not any global property of $M$

Comment: yeah, i think it is...